# In RStudio, is there a way to specify a fig.path for *all* figures for this file?

Tags: r, r-markdown

In RStudio, is there a way to globally specify a fig.path for *all* figures?

Here is what I have in mind.  Say I have two Rmd files located in the same directory: `foo.Rmd` and `bar.Rmd`

If both files are knitted, then figures from both files go to the same directory `figures/`.

How do I separate the figures from the two Rmd files?  For example, figures from foo.Rmd should go to `figures/foo` and files from `bar.Rmd` goes to `figures/bar`.

Answer (score 3):

Add a code chunk to each Rmd file at the beginning of the file prior to any figure being created.  In `foo.Rmd`, add this chunk:

````
```{r}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(fig.path="figures/foo/")
```
````

And, in `bar.Rmd`, add this chunk:

````
```{r}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(fig.path="figures/bar/")
```
````

Note the terminating slash which creates a subdirectory.  Otherwise, you'll end up with *files* with prefixes `foo` and `bar`.

[updated]

Comment: As specified by @koenv it seems that the right syntax is `knitr::opts_chunk$set(fig.path="mydir")`

Answer (score 3):

For the above code to be successfull, at least in my case, I had to write:

```
{r setup}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(fig.path="figures/somedir/")
```

Comment: I probably overlook some things: Please, can you explain the to me what your answer distinguishes from the old answer? Thank you.

Comment: I had to change 2 things as compared to the original answer to make the code work for me: (1) add an 's' to opt_chunk: opts_chunk, and (2) include the package name knitr: knitr::opts_chunk...

Comment: Understood now, thanks. Unfortunately, your current reputation is too low to edit and correct the old answer.